# FreeMarker only parse Camel format to Underline format

Tags: freemarker

When I receive some data from the back end, for example the data string 'AbcDef', does freemarker have some build-in function to parse the string to 'ABC_DEF'?? How can I do with the freemarker template language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
<#function camelToDashed(s)>
  <#return s
      <#-- "fooBar" to "foo_bar": -->
      ?replace('([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1_$2', 'r')
      <#-- "FOOBar" to "FOO_Bar": -->
      ?replace('([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])', '$1_$2', 'r')
      <#-- All of those to "FOO_BAR": -->
      ?upper_case
  >
</#function>

${camelToDashed('AbcDef')}
```

Of course it can done without `#function` too, it's just easier to reuse it this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still wonder, is the string '$1_$2' a regular expression? When the pattern comes to a little complicated, just like from "ISOCertifiedStaff" to "ISO_CERTIFIED_STAFF"? Could it be implemented in pure FreeMarker way?

Comment: Yes, `'$1_$2` is the Java regular expressions replacement syntax; it's not FreeMarker-specific. As of `"ISOCertifiedStaff"`, I have updated the code above so now it handles that too.

Comment: Woah!A graceful solution...Thank you!